# AHK Script to run in background

Tags: autohotkey

I have this very basic AHK Script that i use for a game i play and im trying to get change it up a little to be able to have the script run in the backgroudn so i can continue to do other things whilst it runs. Ive been pointed towards ControlSend but i cant seem to get my head around how to get it to successfully work. The script i have just now presses and releases E every 6.5s until i stop the script.

```
#SingleInstance Force

#z::
  Send, {E down}
  Sleep, 100
  Send, {E up}
  SetTimer, Go, 6000
  Return
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: so, you want `E` to be pressed on your keyboard every 6.5 s no matter what else you are doing? ... wouldn't that mess with web browsing and text editing?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What do you want to do?

Comment: So i've been told that using ControlSend can send an imput to a program thats not the current active program.

Comment: My current aim is to be able to run the script and it continues to press E on that one program and it doesnt have to be the one im focused on.

Comment: I recommend using the autohotkey help file, if you right click on the autohotkey icon and click help, it opens it. That along with the window spy will allow you find all the info you need.

Comment: I have already attempted to use the help file and im unable to understand how to get it working successfully. Hence why i have come to SO.

Comment: So you've used the 'window spy' too?

Comment: If you've used Window Spy like Josh mentioned and it doesn't find a control that you can use, including trying simply *no* control or just `ahk_parent`, you'll either have to find a way with PostMessage/SendMessage (difficult, and possibly very time consuming), or deal with a workaround such as capturing the current active window, `WinActivate`ing the game window, sending your key press, then `WinActivate`ing the saved (previously active) window. You might also consider adding a `BlockInput` during that time